# Is the Michael line star countable?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ is said to be star countable if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a countable subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

Michael line could see [here](http://six.rdaili.com/sohu.com.php?u=ctzzH7iF9TPPeepscdn%2byb0939GDhuXkGUEj8JAsfntVbwUH0%2bnAZ32UQlgwchf5rB5TctYjcdWEn8R7DPTcGqvHf4AOWiCaWtInAQ==&b=3&f=norefer).

> My question is this: Is the Michael line star countable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $K\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ be a Cantor set in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. Then $$\mathscr{U}=\{\Bbb R\setminus K\}\cup\big\{\{x\}:x\in K\big\}$$ is an open cover of the Michael line such that $\operatorname{st}(A,\mathscr{U})\ne\Bbb R$ for any countable $A\subseteq\Bbb R$.