# A question on star countable space

Tags: general-topology

Here is a proposition from the paper of [L.P. Aiken Star-covering properties](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5716). I cannot understand why (the last line) the space is [star countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308922/is-the-michael-line-star-countable). Could somebody help me? Thanks ahead.

The picture is not clear. You could see the Proposition 11 of the paper.

> **Proposition 11.** If $\aleph_0\leq\kappa\leq\mathfrak{c}$, there exists a m.a.d.f. $\mathcal{E}\subseteq [\kappa]^\omega$ such that $\Psi(\mathcal{E})$ is star-countable.
>
> **Proof.** Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ and $\mathcal{D}\subseteq[\kappa\setminus \omega]^\omega$ be maximal almost disjoint families such that $|\mathcal{C}|=|\mathcal{D}|=\mathfrak{c}$. This is possible because $\kappa\leq\mathfrak{c}$. Choose a bijection $f:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$. Define $\mathcal{E}=\{C\cup f(C):C\in\mathcal{C}\}$. If $A\in[\kappa]^\omega$, $|A\cap\omega|=\aleph_0$ or $|A\cap (\kappa\setminus\omega)|=\aleph_0$. In either case, $A$ has infinite intersection with some element of $\mathcal{C}\cup\mathcal{D}$, thus $\mathcal{E}$ is maximal. Then $\Psi(\mathcal{E})$ is star-countable because $\mathsf{St}(\omega,\mathscr{U})=\Psi(\mathcal{E})$, for any open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $\Psi(\mathcal{E})$. $\;\;\Box$

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGQu1.png))

Comment: It sounded like you weren't satisfied with the image quality, so I typed it out; please feel free to correct any mistakes I may have introduced (I'm not familiar with any advanced set theory notations).

Comment: Good Job! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathscr{U}$ is any open cover of $\Psi ( \mathcal{E} )$, it suffices to show $\Psi ( \mathcal{E} ) \setminus \mathrm{st} ( \omega , \mathscr{U} )$ is finite.

- Fist note that every $E \in \mathcal{E}$ belongs to $\mathrm{st} ( \omega , \mathscr{U} )$.  Pick any $U \in \mathscr{U}$ containing $E$.  Then in particular $E \setminus U$ is finite.  Note that $E$ itself is of the form $C \cup f (C)$ where $C \in \mathcal{C}$, and as $C \subseteq \omega$ is infinite it must be that $U \cap \omega$ is infinite, in particular it is nonempty.  Therefore $E \in \mathrm{st} ( \omega , \mathscr{U} )$.
- It follows that $Z = \Psi ( \mathcal{E} ) \setminus \mathrm{st} ( \omega , \mathscr{U} ) \subseteq \kappa$.  I claim that $Z \cap E$ is finite for all $E \in \mathcal{E}$.  Given $E \in \mathcal{E}$ there is a $U \in \mathscr{U}$ such that $E \in U$.  It follows that $E \setminus U$ is finite, and $U \subseteq \mathrm{st} ( \omega , \mathscr{U} )$ (by the observation in the first point).  Therefore $Z \cap U = \emptyset$ and so $Z \cap E \subseteq E \setminus U$ is finite.  Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a m.a.d.f. it follows that $Z$ cannot be infinite.

---

Note that the proof given in the paper is incorrect since given $\alpha \in \kappa \setminus \omega$ the family $$\mathscr{U} = \{ \{ E \} \cup ( E \setminus \{ \alpha \} ) : E \in \mathcal{E} \} \cup \{ \alpha \}$$ is an open cover of $\Psi ( \mathcal{E} )$ but $\alpha \notin \mathrm{st} ( \omega , \mathscr{U} )$.  (Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a m.a.d.f. we may assume without loss of generality that $\bigcup \mathcal{E} = \kappa$.)

Comment: did you go to toposym 1995? We might have met there (you were at Oxford, IIRC?)

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I need some time to take in.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: Thanks. I have got it. You are always Kindful. If I may ask more: Does Such space have **Star countable** subspace of the form like this: $\Psi(\mathcal{E'})=\kappa \cup \mathcal{E'}$, where $\mathcal{E'} \subset \mathcal{E}$ is countable?

Comment: @Henno: You must have me confused with someone else.  I hadn't yet begun my university education in 1995 (and was a few years away from even knowing what a topological space was).

Comment: @ArthurFischer funny, I was pretty sure it was also an Arthur Fischer in topology (though I hadn't heard of him since), working on generalized metric spaces. Too bad then.

Comment: @Paul: You're welcome.  I have altered the proof and example somewhat; no essential changes but I think it is more streamlined.  As to the question in your last comment the answer is no if $\kappa$ is uncountable: as each $E \in\mathcal E^\prime$ is countable it follows that $Z = \kappa\setminus\bigcup\mathcal E^\prime$ is uncountable.  Then $\mathscr{U} = \{ \{ E \} \cup E : E \in \mathcal E^\prime \} \cup \{ \{ \alpha \} : \alpha \in Z \}$ is an open cover of $X = \kappa\cup\mathcal E^\prime$ and $\mathrm{st} ( A , \mathscr U )$ is countable for all countable $A \subseteq X$.